# How can I convert my date to the appropriate format for doing a new Date()?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date coming from the server which comes in the following format: `2018-11-13 05:00:00.000 +00:00`.

I want this to be converted into a date object using `new Date()`, which works fine on Chrome but in none of the other browsers unfortunately.

Here is what I am currently doing that only works on chrome:

```
const dateStr = '2018-11-13 05:00:00.000 +00:00'
const dateObj = new Date(dateStr)
```

My question is, what is the best way I can get `dateStr` in the proper format so my `dateObj` can be a valid date for all other browsers?

Comment: You've tagged this with `momentjs`, which could [parse that format itself](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)...

Comment: You could do `dateStr.replace(' ','T').replace(' ','')` so the string becomes "2018-11-13T05:00:00.000+00:00" which is a valid [ECMAScript date and time string](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `moment` and provide the date format so it knows how to parse the date ... something similar to this:

```
moment('2018-11-13 05:00:00.000 +00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS ZZ').toDate()
```